# Error: cannot find symbol variable action_settings

Tags: java

I keep getting the error message :

> "cannot find symbol variable action_settings"

How can I fix this?

I was getting a similar error mesaage regarding this part:

```
.inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
```

but then I followed the advice from somebody on here about adding a menu file in the res file.

What should I do about this situation?

```js
package com.example.android.courtcounter;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

/**
 * This activity keeps track of the basketball score for 2 teams.
 */
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    // Tracks the score for Team A
    int scoreTeamA = 0;

    // Tracks the score for Team B
    int scoreTeamB = 0;

    
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimpSlifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: import R.id.action_settings?  Or declare it.

Comment: We need to see the XML resource for your "main_menu" declaration to verify your statements and creation of the action_settings menu option

Answer (score 0):

Your menu menu_main shall contain a certain view(id=action_settings).Or you just remove the line

```
if (id == R.id.action_settings)
```